# Efficient data structure for a set of integers

Tags: search, data-structures, collections, set

I'm working on a set of n integers from an interval of [0, m] and I need the following operations:

- find
- remove
- insert
- enumerate (get all entries)
- clear (remove all entries)

At the moment I'm using binary trees / heaps for this but wonder if there is a more efficient data structure. 
I could use uninitialized RAM, as far as I can see requiring O(1) for find / remove / insert, O(n) for enumerate / clear, while needing O(m) space. (e.g. see https://research.swtch.com/sparse)

Is there any data structure requiring less than O(m) space while still maintaining (amortized) worst-case-complexities O(1) for find / remove / insert and O(n) for enumerate / clear?

Please note: Amortized as in: "Given n operations, we have constant * n operations in total, so amortized worst case is O(1)". Not as in: "Given this probability distribution and given assumptions X, Y, Z, average worst case will most probably be in O(1)."
So I'm not looking for hash-table based solutions that will work in O(1) "probably most of the time".

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie  (though it might use hash table)

Comment: Y-fast tries don't need hash tables, but the cost of find/remove/insert is &Theta;(sqrt(log m)), which is super-constant.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such known data structure. See "Mihai Pǎtraşcu: obituary and open problems" by Mikkel Thorup, section 1, Problem 1. "If we want a joint bound for both lookups and updates, the best known bound is O(sqrt(log n / log log n))"